# Ejabberd error: Maximum number of users for conference@conference.url.com has been reached

Tags: ejabberd

We are using ejabberd in conference mode.
My conference has default values.
Such as "Max number of occupants 200", etc

We have 14 participants and 2 owners. When I try to join my account (as a second owner) to conference I've got an error 
"Maximum number of users for conference@conference.url.com has been reached"

The problem appear when more than 2 jabber client (per one user) logged in to the server. It is possible to join to the conference when two client online, but when third one online I've got an error .

Can someone explain why? Maybe there are some other limits ?

Comment: I'm searching for the string "Maximum number of users for" in the ejabberd source code, but I can't find it. What ejabberd version are you using?

Comment: Hey, my ejabberd version is 16.02 and this message appear in Gajim client http://gajim.org

Comment: Hey, any idea's?

Comment: I've tried with ejabberd 18.04, default options, joining a room with three different accounts, all of them owners. Also tried joining the same room with same account with three different clients at the same time. All worked correctly. I cannot try with ejabberd 16.02 because it doesn't compile for me... Your problem is strange, I think it may be configuration, but if you can install a recent ejabberd in another machine and try it, you can confirm if the problem was only in old ejabberd, or it is also in recent versions.

Comment: It seems that bug was in android app.

Answer (score 0):

I've updated Conversation to the latest version and problem disappear.
It seems that bug was in android app.

Thanks to everyone!